# Get values from an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This code get a user to enter 5 numbers, stores the in an array, and works out the average

```
double average;
double variance;
int i;
int[] arr = new int[5]; // 5 size array

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\n Enter your number:\t");
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine("\n");
average = arr.Sum() / 5.0;
Console.WriteLine("\n The average is {0}", average);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I am trying to work out the variance which is  (number – average) * (number – average).

However I am unsure on how to pull out each number from the array and perform this calculation?

Any help much appreciated thanks

Comment: You can use a loop like you did to get the user input.

Comment: It's almost identical to what you did to put the values in.  Just mimic that pattern.

Comment: Not sure why you *compute* average instead of using existing [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534635%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)... would make sense if you compute sum with `for`, but you already use LINQ to get `Sum`...

Answer (score 8):

You can get the standard deviation as follows:

```
double average = arr.Average();
double sumOfSquaresOfDifferences = arr.Select(val => (val - average) * (val - average)).Sum();
double sd = Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquaresOfDifferences / arr.Length);
```

Comment: Or use `var sd = arr.Select(v=>(v-average)*(v-average)).Average();` and skip the `sumOfSquaresOfDifferences` altogether.

Comment: @juharr That won't return the correct value. You forget the `Math.Sqrt(double)` portion. (Very important for Standard Deviation.)

Answer (score 1):

### Your Question

Make an Extension Method.. not Tested but it should work if [what is described here](http://www.frustfrei-lernen.de/mathematik/varianz-berechnen.html) is correct

```
static class MathsExtensions
{
    public static double GetVariance(this double[] values)
    {
        var avg = values.Average();
        return values.Select(value => (value - avg) * (value - avg)).Sum() / values.Count();
    }
}
```

Just gave it a little test.

```
        double[] arr = { 8, 7, 9, 10, 6 };
        Console.WriteLine(arr.GetVariance());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

It returns 2 which - according to my link - is correct.

#### This might be helpful in the feauture

If you next Time have a similar Problem, you should propably just google like "how do i calculate variance" and then create your algorithm based on the theory. **But alaways look up if there does already exist a solution**

Comment: I won't press you, but there's alaways the possibility to accept an answer :)